# Wordpress on Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, windows-10, iis-10

I am trying to get Wordpress running on my Windows 10 machine i.e on IIS 10. I have used the Web Platform Installer (WPI) to install MySql and PHP. WPI did hang when installing Wordpress (WP) so I decided to install it manually.

Here is what I have got so far.......

- MySQL has been installed and Workbench connects successfully.
- I have created a new database/schema and User for WP in MySQL and Workbench connects successfully using those credentials as well.
- I have created a folder and configured that in IIS. Host headers et al.
- I can confirm that PHP requests are being served as I dropped a PHP file with a 'print' command and can see the results.
- I have downloaded the latest version of WP and have dropped the contents into this folder.
- wp-config.php has been edited to reflect correct database information.

Despite all this....

- http://websitename - gives me **'Error establishing a database connection'**
- http://websitename/wp-admin - gives me **'Error establishing a database connection'**

Any thoughts on the above?

Comment: see if any magic happens when you add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to the wp config file. https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Have you installed WordPress through the installer? You need to delete wp-config.php and access the installer by going to you website.

Comment: @kks21199: I just tried deleting the wp-config.php and accessing the site. It took me to the installer pages and requested for DB information. I supplied root credentials and I still get the same EEDC screen.

Comment: Well, bit different suggestion away from question, but why don't you try "WAMP" or "XAMPP" for windows? Installation and configuration of WAMP or XAMPP is easy on windows and wordpress configuration is also easy.

Comment: @Noel, did you test the connection after you entered the details before clicking next? You have to make sure the database exists, and is empty. Maybe instead of using root password, create a user with sufficient permission for just that database.

Comment: @kks21199: I have created a separate user credentials for the wp site, I have successful connections using Workbench and command line C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u username -p dbname.

Comment: @zipkundan:  I am thinking of that as a last resort. Thanks.

Comment: Total side step suggestion. [vvv](http://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/) is the official WordPress development vagrant ans also works on windows. maybe give that a try

Comment: I suggest creating a `db-test.php` and try to connect manualy using [mysqli_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). That way you can be sure WordPress is or isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set this up following @kks21199's suggestion of '**setting up WordPress through the installer**'

For detailed instructions, follow [this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-your-windows-computer-using-wamp/) article.